# Phrasing a block differently returns different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I was testing a few pieces of code out, and two statements that should return the same value return different values.

```js
const arr = [3, 'foo', { bar: 'baz' }, false, 4, 5];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 i = arr[i]
 console.log(i)
}
```

returns `[3, 4, 5]`, while

```js
const arr = [3, 'foo', { bar: 'baz' }, false, 4, 5];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 console.log(arr[i])
}
```

returns `[3, 'foo', { bar: 'baz' }, false, 4, 5]`

Why?

Comment: You are modifying the indexer `i` in each iteration of the loop, so that's why you are getting different result.

Comment: In the first round of the first loop you set `i` to `3` and therefor skip the elements at index `1`, `2`, and `3` (which is not really relevant because you're logging `i` and not `arr[i]`)

Comment: In the first loop, you are messing with the `i` variable, meaning it starts at `0` and then it becomes `3` right after that. It is *almost never* a good idea to change the indexer of your loop *inside the for-loop body*, unless you (a) know what you are doing, and (b) have very specific and well-thought-out reasons to do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think second snippet explains itself only the first one needs explanation.

First of all there is no sense to write `i = arr[i]` inside a loop. It changes the looping number of the element at corresponding index. Which means anything unexpected could happen

What happened in your case is below

1. In first iteration `i` is `0` then its changed to `3` due to `i = arr[i]`.
2. In second iteration `i` is `4` because last value of `i` is incremented due to `i++`. Due to `i = arr[i]` `i` becomes `4` the `arr[4]`
3. In third iteration `i` becomes `5` due to increment `i++` and due `i = arr[i]` it remains `5`.
4. In fourth iteration it becomes `6` and loop ends because `i < arr.length` becomes false

```js
const arr = [3, 'foo', { bar: 'baz' }, false, 4, 5];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Initial i = ${i}`)
  i = arr[i];
  console.log(`Final i = ${i}`);
  console.log('\n')
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for downvote. Is there anything wrong or missing in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example of both the flexibility and pitfalls of imperative programming.

tl;dr you shouldn't be modifying `i` in you're for loops, and you also shouldn't be using `for` loops. A better way to iterate over the array is:

```
arr.forEach(function(item, i) { 
  console.log(item)
})
```

**Imperative Programming**

Copied from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming): In computer science, imperative programming is a programming paradigm that uses statements that change a program's state.

**What does this mean?**

In simple terms, whenever you are modifying variables (mutation), you're programming imperatively. For example:

```
var x = 1;
x = 5;
console.log(x + 5); // you would get 10
```

However, this can lead to unexpected problems which we can see in your example which is explained pretty well in other answers.

This is why in general, it's a good idea to avoid it (at least in Javascript) even though *imperative programming* is so convenient. This doesn't mean we always avoid it. Sometimes, programs need to run as efficient as possible, and *imperatively* modifying variables is the only way to achieve that.

In most cases, we don't need that efficiency if we're iterating (looping) through only a few hundred or even tens of thousands of variables. Our computers are fast enough that the difference in performance is not worth it.

**Functional Programming**

Functional programming is a great alternative. In practice, it boils down to one simple rule - no side effects. Side effects simply mean mutation, i.e modifying variables.

This avoids bugs that would be introduced in imperative programming since you know that once you initialize a variable, it will always be the same.

Below, I'll outline a pseudo introduction to functional programming and how it relates to your example. If you want to learn more about it, you can find countless resources online. Here's a pretty good [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-functional-programming-in-javascript-a-complete-guide-e85ed13b42c8) about functional programming with Javascript.

Some examples of functional programming

```
const x = 5; // we use const do denote x is constant and can't be changed ever
// x = 5 would give us an error!
const y = x + 5
// for (const i = 0; i < 10; ++i) is not functional since i is modified!
```

**How should we loop without for loops?** Recursion!
It's almost always good to avoid using for loops in the form of `for (var i ...)`. This is because those loops are based on imperative programming, which we want to avoid if possible.

How do we print all the values of an array?

```
function printValues(arr, i = 0) {
  if (i == arr.length) return; // exit when we reach the end
  console.log(arr[i]); // let's call console.log
  printValues(arr, i + 1); // do the same thing with the next index of the array
}
```

What if instead of just printing, we want to double every element in the array and double it? Instead of rewriting the same function, we can generalize this:

```
function forEach(arr, method, i = 0) {
  if (i == arr.length) return;
  method(arr[i], i)
  return forEach(arr, method, i + 1)
}

// notice that forEach looks exactly like printValues, except now, we can pass in anything we would have passed into a normal for loop
forEach([1,2,3,4,5], function(item, i) {
  const x = i * 2
  console.log(x);
})

// now back to OP's example, we can use this forEach function
forEach(arr, function (item, i) {
  console.log(item)
})
```

Of course, Javascript has these functions built-in and they are also optimized. So, you can just use the built-in forEach:

```
arr.forEach(function(item, i) {
  console.log(item)
  // or console.log(arr[i]);
})
```

There are other functions to use too other than `forEach`, these include:

1. `map`
2. `filter`
3. `reduce`

There are more, but these are the fundamental building blocks for iteration on arrays in functional Javascript and are must-haves in your toolkit!

Comment: _"and you also shouldn't be using `for` loops"_ - That's a really bold statement which you definitely can prove it in detail.